# Slideshow with Fade displays all texts when refreshed instead of one at a time

Tags: jquery, slideshow, visibility, google-widget

I am currently trying to figure out how to fix this problem for the longest time and I'm not even sure exactly what the problem is :( . I found this "Auto-Scrolling Slideshow" tutorial using jquery and tweaked it to fit my site. But whenever I refresh the page, the slideshow on the top right displays all the quotes I have at once for a brief couple of seconds before collapsing to showing just 1 quote at a time. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to fix this?

I have a google stock ticker widget embedded onto that page as well and it seems like the problem arose when I embedded the code in Chrome, FF, and Safari BUT in IE 8, the problem is visible regardless. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this for I am stumped after staring at this for almost the entire day! :(

here is the link to what I'm currently working on:

Thank you so much in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set `style="dispaly:none"`  for the

```
<div id="quoteshow"  style="display:none" >
```

And try again

Comment: hmm, thanks for the suggestion but I tried that and it hides the entire slideshow...

Comment: try unhiding it just before you assign to the slider

Comment: NVM, I managed to fixed the problem by adding a height to the slides. thanks for the attempted help tho!